# foreach collection reference type nested property update

Tags: c#-4.0, collections, types, foreach

I see numerous examples on foreach collection reference type property update, but not quite what I am struggling with. What if you want to update a property of a property of the reference type item? like so:

```
 public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public EmployeeType EmpType { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmployeeType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        private IList<Employee> existingEmp;

        public void edit()
        {
            var dbEmployees = GetExistingEmployees();

            IList<Employee> employees = new List<Employee> { 
                new Employee{ Id = 1, Name="me", EmpType = new EmployeeType { Id = 1}}, 
                new Employee{ Id = 2, Name="me again", EmpType = new EmployeeType { Id = 2}}
            };

            foreach (var emp in employees)
            {
                foreach (var oldEmp in dbEmployees)
                {
                    if (emp.Id == oldEmp.Id)
                    {
                        UpdateChanges(emp, oldEmp);
                        existingEmp.Add(oldEmp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }        

        private void UpdateChanges(Employee emp, Employee oldEmp){
            if (oldEmp.EmpType.Id != emp.EmpType.Id)
            {
                LogChange();
                oldEmp.EmpType.Id = emp.EmpType.Id;
            }
        }

        private void LogChange()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        //data access layer
        public IList<Employee> GetExistingEmployees()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

The issue here is the last employee in the collection if his/her employee type property Id changed in a ddl, updating it will cascade to all other employees' emp type in the collection. That is nutts. Due to the logging requirement I can not use lambda or other fancy construct. I need hep with fixing this with in foreach or for loops.

EDIT:

As expected the same code structure works somewhere else in my application. I don't get the last item's property updating bleeding to other items' properties.

I solved this using a hacky approach:

```
private void UpdateChanges(Employee emp, Employee oldEmp){
    var oldEmpTemp = GetEmployeeById(oldEmp.Id);

    if (oldEmp.EmpType.Id != emp.EmpType.Id)
    {
        LogChange();
        oldEmpTemp.EmpType.Id = emp.EmpType.Id;
    }
    //instead of updating the collection items
    // and bulk updating in the db, update directly in the db
    UpdateEmployee(oldEmpTemp);    
}
```

But still can't explain why it's not working for this instance.

Comment: You've got your syntax wrong, it should be `for (auto emp : employees)`, and `->` instead of `.` in lots of places.

Comment: Please add an appropriate language tag. Is this C#?

Comment: corrected the syntax issues...